# Unable to display Icon onTap in flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

I was trying to display an icon over a text whenever the ontap function is called.

```
onTap: () {
                                if (cellStatus['$j$k'] ?? true) {
                                  print('working');
                                  setState(() {
                                    cellStatus.addAll({'$j$k': false});
                                    Icon(Icons.access_alarm);
                                  });
                                }
                              },
```

Where am I going wrong..

Comment: You did not add the `Icon` to the widget tree, you cannot call widgets like functions

Comment: Can you add some reference/image of the end result? Where do you want the `Icon` to be shown?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your widget

```flutter
            InkWell(
               onTap:(){
                  setState(() {
                                cellStatus['$j$k'] = true;
                              });
               } ,
                 
           child: !cellStatus['$j$k'] ? Text("example text") : 
                  Icon(Icons.access_alarm) ,
              
             ),
```

Comment: add this condition to that text child as i have suggested